# How would you remove a created node from one div and display it to another div using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I created function add_item that listens for a click event. each time the button is clicked the function will create a div element and append a new div to the output div( parent node ) and when I click on one of the created divs that particular child will be removed using the delete_item function but what I really want to know now is **how to take the removed item and add it into another div like onclick of a created node remove that precise one from output 1 and now display it to output 2 using Vanilla Js only** not jQuery.

```js
var add_item_button = document.getElementById(`add_item_button`);
var output = document.getElementById(`output`);

add_item_button.addEventListener(`click`, add_item);

function add_item() {
  let create_div = document.createElement(`div`);
  create_div.setAttribute(`class`, `added_div`);
  output.appendChild(create_div);
  
  create_div.addEventListener(`click`, delete_item);
  function delete_item(){
  output.removeChild(create_div);
  } 
}
```

```css
.added_div {
  background-color: #000;
  margin:5px;
  height: 50px; 
  width:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_item_button">add item</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `output2.appendChild(create_div);`

Demo:

```js
var add_item_button = document.getElementById(`add_item_button`);
var output = document.getElementById(`output`);
var output2 = document.getElementById(`output2`);

add_item_button.addEventListener(`click`, add_item);

function add_item() {
  let create_div = document.createElement(`div`);
  create_div.setAttribute(`class`, `added_div`);
  output.appendChild(create_div);
  
  create_div.addEventListener(`click`, delete_item);
  function delete_item(){
    output2.appendChild(create_div); // <-----------------------------
  } 
}
```

```css
.added_div {
  background-color: #000;
  margin:5px;
  height: 50px; 
  width:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_item_button">add item</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
```

Comment: thank you I truly appreciate it. I was really overthinking then . This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append the element to a new parent. Element references are exactly that, so unless you make a clone of the element, the element itself is moved.

```js
var add_item_button = document.getElementById(`add_item_button`);
var output = document.getElementById(`output`);
var moved = document.getElementById('moved');

add_item_button.addEventListener(`click`, add_item);

function add_item() {
  let create_div = document.createElement(`div`);
  create_div.setAttribute(`class`, `added_div`);
  output.appendChild(create_div);
  
  create_div.addEventListener(`click`, delete_item);
  function delete_item(){
    //Just change the div. It's one object/element that is moved
    moved.appendChild(this);
  } 
}
```

```css
.added_div {
  background-color: #000;
  margin:5px;
  height: 50px; 
  width:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_item_button">add item</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<h2>Moved</h2>
<div id="moved"></div>
```

Let's now take advantage of event bubbling so you don't have to bind an event listener every time you add an element.

```js
var add_item_button = document.getElementById(`add_item_button`);
var output = document.getElementById(`output`);
var moved = document.getElementById('moved');

add_item_button.addEventListener(`click`, add_item);

function add_item() {
  let create_div = document.createElement(`div`);
  create_div.setAttribute(`class`, `added_div`);
  output.appendChild(create_div);  
 
}

//Event listener on output element
output.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  //Check it is the added div that is clicked using CSS selector
  if(event.target.matches(".added_div")) {
    //Move the element
    moved.appendChild(event.target);
  }
});
```

```css
.added_div {
  background-color: #000;
  margin:5px;
  height: 50px; 
  width:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_item_button">add item</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<h2>Moved</h2>
<div id="moved"></div>
```